# Generating report using Crystal Reports on ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports

After reserving a ticket for an travel agency, I want generate a `printable report` using `Crystal Report`.

I'm looking for a way to do that.

Any video tutorial or something like that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is it.

Creating Crystal Report with Multiple Tables in ASP.NET :

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/556_Creating_Crystal_Report_with_Multiple_Tables_in_ASP_NET.aspx

Export Crystal Reports to Different File Formats :

http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/553_Export_Crystal_Reports_to_Different_File_Formats.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports CrystalDecisions
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports System.IO

Public Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

    Protected Sub LinkButton1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LinkButton1.Click

        OpenPDF(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Reports/Report.pdf")

    End Sub


    Private Sub OpenPDF(downloadAsFilename As String)
        Dim RptDoc As New ReportDocument()
        RptDoc.Load(Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/Reports/myreport.rpt"))
        RptDoc.SetDatabaseLogon("user", "password", "server", "database")

        Dim stream As New BinaryReader(RptDoc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.[Shared].ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat))
        Response.ClearContent()
        Response.ClearHeaders()
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", Convert.ToString("attachment; filename=") & downloadAsFilename)
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", stream.BaseStream.Length.ToString())
        Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)))
        Response.Flush()
        Response.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```